# How to avoid notices in my page php?

Tags: php, html

I'm developping a page web with html and php but when i run my code i obtain notices in my page like this

```
   1345224199 [INFO]: Connecting to tcp://192.168.1.6:5222 
   1345224199 [VERBOSE]: Socket is ready; send it. 
   1345224199 [VERBOSE]: SENT: 
   1345224199 [VERBOSE]: Successfully sent 112 bytes. 
   1345224199 [VERBOSE]: Disconnecting...  
   1345224199 [VERBOSE]: Socket is ready; send it. 
   1345224199 [VERBOSE]: SENT: 
   1345224199 [VERBOSE]: Successfully sent 16 bytes. 
   1345224199 [VERBOSE]: RECV: 
   1345224199 [VERBOSE]: RECV: DIGEST-MD5PLAINANONYMOUSCRAM-MD5zlib 
   1345224199 [DEBUG]: Calling features_handler 
   1345224199 [VERBOSE]: Socket is ready; send it. 
   1345224199 [VERBOSE]: SENT: 
   1345224199 [VERBOSE]: Successfully sent 73 bytes. 
   1345224199 [DEBUG]: EVENT: end_stream
```

How can i avoid displaying this notices in my page web?

Comment: <?php
error_reporting(0);
include("xmpphp/XMPPHP/xmpp.php");
$conn = new XMPPHP_XMPP('192.168.1.65','5222','admin','admin', 'xmpphp','emna-pc', $printlog=true, $loglevel=XMPPHP_Log::LEVEL_VERBOSE);

        try {.....}catch (XMPPHP_Exception $e) {
             die($e->getMessage());
         }
   
?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with `$loglevel=XMPPHP_Log::LEVEL_ERROR`, it will show you only errors, or `$loglevel=null` for nothing.

```
<?php
    error_reporting(0);
    include("xmpphp/XMPPHP/xmpp.php");
    $conn = new XMPPHP_XMPP('192.168.1.65','5222','admin','admin', 'xmpphp','emna-pc', $printlog=true, $loglevel=XMPPHP_Log::LEVEL_ERROR);
    try {.....}
    catch (XMPPHP_Exception $e) { 
        die($e->getMessage()); 
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you are using CURL and have `verbose` set to be on. Try setting `CURLOPT_VERBOSE` to false:

```
curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_VERBOSE, false);
```

Comment: Whoa, I have never seen that before. (*googles* it) Would my answer still work?

Comment: this line blocks the script, the page stop appearing

Comment: Sounds like a syntax error. Turn error_reporting on to see what the issue is.

Answer (score -1):

You get notices due to the level of error reporting your allowing to display. It's a good idea to have this turned on with your development site, but it should be turned completely off on your production site. 
Turn OFF all errors:

```
error_reporting(0);
```

Turn ON all errors:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: That's weird. This should turn off all notices from PHP regardless of what your doing.